# prime ng table performance issue on more than 100 columns

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, primeng, p-table

I use prime ng table, **p-table**, to display large amounts of data. lets say 20k rows and 500 columns.

I use virual scroll for the rows to render dynamically.

The table is smooth when there are 20k rows and 20 columns.

But when the number of columns increases the table lags significantly that sometimes it kills the browser.

What is the common practice to handle large number of columns to have better performance?

I clarify that even with 300 rows and 150 columns its slow.

Thanks

Comment: You need to revise the necessity of showing 500 columns and 10k+ rows at once. I don't think it is just a PrimeNG table issue, you need to consider how long the API fetches the data from the database (query performance, indexing) and returns the response to the front-end.

Comment: Consider all the data preloaded. so its the matter of rendering. even with 300 rows and 150 columns its slow.

Comment: virtual scroll is only applied vertically. I think you need to implement a horizontal virtual scroll too. Its clearly too many dom elements rendering that is the issue. How is it even readable with that many columns ?

Comment: Please share with me if there is a way to add a virtual scroll horizontally for a table.
the virtual scroll for rows works fine in p-table.